# R ggplot warning when using geom_ribbon: no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quick question when using `ggplot2` - I use the data below and as soon as I use `geom_ribbon()`, I get the following error message:

```r
Warning message:
In max(ids, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I presume that this has something to do with the `group` aspect of ggplot (and the fact that there are NA's).

Here is the main command (data at the bottom):

```r
library(tidyverse)

a %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time,y = fitted)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = cf_lwr, ymax = cf_upr, fill = "red", group = name), alpha = 0.5, na.rm = FALSE)
#> Warning in max(ids, na.rm = TRUE): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -
#> Inf
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

When I vary this slightly (removing the `group` argument), I don't get an error, but the plot is not correct:

```r
a %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time,y = fitted)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = cf_lwr, ymax = cf_upr, fill = "red"), alpha = 0.5, na.rm = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What does the error mean? Can I simply suppress it?

Any ideas?

Many thanks!!

### Update

Thanks to the comments to this question - this is what I'm finally attempting to get - so the geom_ribbons should only be displayed in certain areas - that's why having a few NA's is intended.

But perhaps there is a better way to deal with this

```r
a %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time,y = fitted)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = fitted, color = id)) + 
  #facet_wrap(~id)+
  geom_line(aes(y = cf, group = id))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = cf_lwr, ymax = cf_upr, fill = "red", group = name), alpha = 0.5, na.rm = FALSE)
#> Warning: Removed 64 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
#> Warning in max(ids, na.rm = TRUE): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -
#> Inf
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Data

```r
a <- structure(list(id = c("Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
                           "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
                           "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
                           "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
                           "Austria", "Austria", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
                           "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
                           "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
                           "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
                           "Belgium", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", 
                           "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", 
                           "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", 
                           "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", 
                           "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", 
                           "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", 
                           "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", 
                           "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", "Croatia", 
                           "Croatia", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus"), 
                    name = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "fesisAustria.2001", "fesisAustria.2001", 
                             "fesisAustria.2001", "fesisAustria.2001", "fesisAustria.2001", 
                             "fesisAustria.2001", "fesisAustria.2001", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                             NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                             NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                             NA, NA, NA, NA, "fesisBulgaria.1998", "fesisBulgaria.1998", 
                             "fesisBulgaria.1998", "fesisBulgaria.1998", "fesisBulgaria.1998", 
                             "fesisBulgaria.1998", "fesisBulgaria.1998", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                             NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "fesisBulgaria.2014", "fesisBulgaria.2014", 
                             "fesisBulgaria.2014", "fesisBulgaria.2014", "fesisBulgaria.2014", 
                             "fesisBulgaria.2014", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                             "fesisCroatia.2005", "fesisCroatia.2005", "fesisCroatia.2005", 
                             "fesisCroatia.2005", "fesisCroatia.2005", "fesisCroatia.2005", 
                             "fesisCroatia.2005", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                             NA, NA, NA), 
                    time = c(1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 
                             2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
                             2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 1995, 1996, 
                             1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
                             2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
                             2017, 2018, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 
                             2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
                             2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 
                             1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
                             2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
                             1995, 1996, 1997, 1998), 
                    y = c(-6.27, -6.17, -6.23, -6.11, 
                          -6.15, -6.1, -6.03, -5.93, -5.87, -5.86, -5.84, -5.91, -5.9, 
                          -5.96, -5.99, -5.96, -5.99, -6, -5.96, -5.99, -5.98, -5.95, 
                          -5.94, -5.92, -6.16, -6.14, -6.13, -6.1, -6.09, -6.08, -6.05, 
                          -6.05, -6.03, -6, -6.03, -6.01, -5.99, -5.99, -6.03, -6.07, 
                          -6.1, -6.14, -6.16, -6.15, -6.09, -6.11, -6.11, -6.11, -7.67, 
                          -7.65, -7.63, -7.41, -7.37, -7.43, -7.37, -7.3, -7.16, -7.1, 
                          -7, -6.93, -6.96, -6.89, -6.89, -6.91, -6.9, -6.86, -6.97, 
                          -6.84, -6.73, -6.71, -6.66, -6.66, -7.35, -7.26, -7.14, -7.09, 
                          -7.03, -7.01, -6.96, -6.89, -6.79, -6.76, -6.72, -6.66, -6.6, 
                          -6.61, -6.61, -6.64, -6.66, -6.69, -6.68, -6.68, -6.62, -6.57, 
                          -6.49, -6.47, -6.37, -6.36, -6.34, -6.31), 
                    fitted = c(-6.23, 
                               -6.2, -6.19, -6.15, -6.13, -6.13, -5.97, -5.95, -5.94, -5.91, 
                               -5.91, -5.9, -5.88, -5.88, -5.92, -5.92, -5.93, -5.96, -5.98, 
                               -5.99, -6, -5.98, -5.97, -5.98, -6.18, -6.16, -6.13, -6.11, 
                               -6.09, -6.09, -6.08, -6.06, -6.05, -6.01, -6.01, -6.01, -5.99, 
                               -6.02, -6.04, -6.04, -6.08, -6.11, -6.13, -6.12, -6.11, -6.09, 
                               -6.08, -6.1, -7.65, -7.59, -7.71, -7.35, -7.43, -7.41, -7.34, 
                               -7.25, -7.18, -7.11, -7.05, -6.99, -6.93, -6.89, -6.9, -6.9, 
                               -6.9, -6.92, -6.92, -6.81, -6.76, -6.71, -6.67, -6.65, -7.24, 
                               -7.15, -7.09, -7.07, -7.08, -7.07, -6.97, -6.92, -6.87, -6.82, 
                               -6.61, -6.58, -6.54, -6.54, -6.6, -6.62, -6.65, -6.7, -6.71, 
                               -6.71, -6.67, -6.62, -6.58, -6.56, -6.28, -6.29, -6.31, -6.28
                    ), 
                    cf = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.13, -6.12, -6.11, -6.1, 
                           -6.07, -6.07, -6.06, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                           NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                           NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -7.71, 
                           -7.66, -7.74, -7.72, -7.65, -7.56, -7.49, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                           NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.92, -6.9, -6.85, -6.8, -6.76, -6.74, 
                           NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.82, -6.8, -6.77, -6.73, 
                           -6.73, -6.79, -6.81, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                           NA, NA, NA), 
                    cf_upr = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.13, -6.18, 
                               -6.16, -6.15, -6.12, -6.12, -6.11, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                               NA, NA, -7.71, -7.73, -7.81, -7.79, -7.72, -7.63, -7.56, 
                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.92, -6.96, -6.91, 
                               -6.85, -6.81, -6.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.82, 
                               -6.84, -6.81, -6.77, -6.77, -6.83, -6.86, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                    cf_lwr = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                               NA, -6.13, -6.07, -6.06, -6.04, -6.02, -6.02, -6.01, NA, 
                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -7.71, -7.59, -7.67, -7.65, -7.58, 
                               -7.49, -7.42, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.92, 
                               -6.84, -6.8, -6.74, -6.7, -6.69, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                               NA, NA, NA, -6.82, -6.75, -6.72, -6.68, -6.68, -6.74, -6.76, 
                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                    cf_upr99 = c(NA, 
                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.13, -6.19, -6.18, -6.16, -6.14, -6.14, 
                                 -6.13, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -7.71, -7.75, -7.83, 
                                 -7.81, -7.74, -7.65, -7.59, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                 NA, -6.92, -6.97, -6.93, -6.87, -6.83, -6.82, NA, NA, NA, 
                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.82, -6.86, -6.83, -6.79, -6.79, 
                                 -6.85, -6.87, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                 NA), 
                    cf_lwr99 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.13, -6.06, -6.04, 
                                 -6.03, -6, -6, -5.99, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -7.71, 
                                 -7.57, -7.64, -7.63, -7.56, -7.47, -7.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.92, -6.82, -6.78, -6.72, -6.68, -6.67, 
                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.82, -6.74, -6.71, 
                                 -6.67, -6.67, -6.73, -6.75, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                 NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There are missing values i.e. `NA` in your upper and lower bounds in `geom_ribbon` You need to fix your data frame first. Removing rows with NAs is what I would do. something like: `na.omit(a)`

Comment: After a look at your data I would guess that it's messed up and something went wrong when preparing the data, i.e. for each of your countries your `name` column contains a lot of NAs. Also where there is an NA in the name column there are NAs in your `cf` columns. Hence, when you `group` by name all obs with an NA in the name column are treated as one group and for this group there are only NAs in cf. That's what geom_ribbon is complaining. To fix that I would suggest to have a look at your data wrangling steps.

Comment: Thanks Jack and Stefan!
I added some more to the question to show you where I want to get in the end - the NA's are generally intended - I want to show an alternative path for a few periods only in certain places. See the figure above. So the figure gets me the right plot, just with errors.

Comment: Hi Moritz. Okay. I See. If that is desired than everything is fine. After all the "error" is just a warning. But to silent the warning you could filter the datasets used in geom_ribbon and the second geom_line, i.e do `geom_ribbon(data = filter(a, !is.na(name)), ...)`and `geom_line(data = filter(a, !is.na(name)), aes(y = cf, group = name))` where I mapped name on the group aes instead of id.